# Java character encoding to HTML ISO-8859-1

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a byte[] containing the value -110 (and other negative values). When I convert it to string I need it to display a ’ (right single quote). Currently, I am getting a question mark (?)

The ’ aligns to the special ASCII character #146 mentioned in [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_8859.asp) but I am now stuck as to how I can input -110 or 146 (-110+256) and be a ’ value. I have also trued Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
byte[] b = {-110,84};
System.out.println(new String(b, Charset.forName("Windows-1252"))); //Displays ?T . The desired output should be ’T
System.out.println(new String(b, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))); //Displays ?T . The desired output should be ’T
System.out.println(new String(b, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))); //Displays ?T . The desired output should be ’T
```

Comment: Your console probably can't print that character. When I try your code, it works fine with the first variant.

Comment: Your link doesn't work, but [U+0092](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/92/index.htm) is a private use character. Note that ASCII doesn't contain anything over 127 - there's no such thing as "special ASCII". It looks like the character you want (the ’ you pasted) is U+2019. That's not part of ISO-8859-1.

Comment: The page you've now linked claims that "In ISO-8859-1, the characters from 128 to 159 are not defined." That's not quite true - it's true for ISO 8859-1, but not for ISO-8859-1. (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)) The page you linked to isn't terribly clear, but I suspect the part you're looking at is using Windows-1252, but that your console doesn't support it.

Comment: Take it from a person with umlauted characters in his name: There is an extended ASCII for every language, dialect, OS and/or phase of the moon, so it's probably a good idea to use Unicode.

Comment: @HeikkiMäenpää: I'd try to avoid the term "extended ASCII" entirely, as it causes pretty much nothing but confusion.

Comment: @Chris The encoding for the bytes is what it is. If you say it is Windows-1252, don't let an attempt to display it convince you otherwise. `new String(b, Charset.forName("Windows-1252"))[0] == '’'`. On the other hand, if you are guessing, these are equally valid: windows-1250, windows-1251, Windows-1252, windows-1253, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257, windows-1258, windows-874.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses as John Skeet points out in his reply, the Java program needed to recognize the input data Windows-1252 and the Windows command line wasn't set to the code page either.

Setting the **command line codepage** to Windows-1252 was done by running

```
chcp 1252
```

**Starting the Java program** to use Windows-1252 as the default was done by adding the following parameter

```
-Dfile.encoding="Windows-1252"
```